# how can merge two array in smarty and php

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

I have an array in which pre assessment, post assessment marks and id should 
be common with my first array. I have to merge both the arrays and print in 
table format using html_table.

I search a lot in smarty but i can not understand how to use html_table in smarty for merging two array.

Kindly push me forward in right direction what can i do for this.

PHP:

```
<?php
    $users = array(
            1 => array(
                'id' => '00AC',
                'pre' =>  50,
                'post' => 60
                ),
            2 => array(
                'id' => '00XV',
                'pre' =>  60,
                'post' => 70
                )
        );

    $user_second = array(
        1 => array(
            'id' => '00AC',
            'name' => 'john',
            'pre' =>  50,
            'post' => 60
            'address' => 'California',
            'email' => 'JOHn@yAh00.com',
            'dob' => '1989/10/06',
            'doj' => '2014/12/04'
        ),
        2 => array(
            'id' => '00XV',
            'name' => 'brad',
            'pre' =>  60,
            'post' => 70,
            'address' => 'Washington',
            'email' => 'bRAd@gmail.com',
            'dob' => '1980/09/23',
            'doj' => '2005/03/10'
        )
    );
    $theme->assign("head",$users);
    $theme->assign("tab",$user_second);
?>
```

Smarty:

```
<{html_table loop=$head}>
        <table class="table table-striped container">
            <thead>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Pre</th>
                <th>Post</th>
                <th>Addres</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>DOB</th>
                <th>DOJ</th>
            </thead>
            <{html_table loop=$tab}>
            <{foreach from = $head key = title item = file}>
                <tr>
                    <td><{$file.id}></th>
                    <td><{$file.name|ucfirst}></td>
                    <td><{$file.pre}></td>
                    <td><{$file.post}></td>
                    <td><{$file.address}></td>
                    <td><{$file.email}></td>
                    <td><{$file.dob}></td>
                    <td><{$file.doj}></td>
                </tr>
            <{/foreach}>
        </table>
```

Comment: Smarty is __template__ engine, it only shows data. Prepare your data in php-file and pass to smarty, simple, isn't it?

Comment: But its not merge my arrays together.